# Dropwizard: How to add a custom validation for GET / PUT

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard service in which I am trying to implement request validation, and below is the code for same.

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/system-info")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SystemInfo {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    public Response testValidation(@QueryParam("name") String name,
    @QueryParam("phoneNo") Long phoneNo,
    @QueryParam("email") String email,
    @QueryParam("password") String password) {
      if(email == null) {
        return Response.ok(ImmutableMap.of("status", "email missing")).build();
      }
      //bunch of other validations
      return Response.ok(ImmutableMap.of("status", "ok")).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/post")
    public Response testPostValidation(final Person person) {
        if(person.getEmail() == null) {
          return Response.ok(ImmutableMap.of("status", "email missing")).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(ImmutableMap.of("status", "ok")).build();
    }
}

class Person {
  @JsonProperty
  private String name;
  @JsonProperty
  private String email;
  @JsonProperty
  private long phoneNo;
  @JsonProperty
  private String password;

  public String getEmail(){
    return email;
  }
  public Person(){};
}
```

In both the GET and POST method I have the QueryParams and the Person object which I would like to be validated.

I have the validation logic inside the Resource class itself, I can create a separate class and replace the if statements with

```
//if(email == null) {
//        return Response.ok(ImmutableMap.of("status", "email missing")).build();
//}
if(!CustomValidater.validate(email, name, phone, password)) {
return Response.ok(ImmutableMap.of("status", "data missing")).build();
}
```

and do the same for POST as well this way the validation logic is abstracted in different class.

Is this the correct way of doing the validation or should I create custom annotation that will do this validation?

Comment: I would expect Dropwizard to support Bean Validation. Note also that you _really_ should not be returning 200 OK for an error condition; that's what 4xx (in this case, probably 400 Bad Request) is for.

Comment: [Please read the documentation](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.14/docs/manual/validation.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should create custom validator, or add constraints validation to model.

Person should have properties like:

```
@NotNull 
private String name;
@NotEmpty
private String surname;
...
```

And  should be validated as method parameter if needed:

```
@Valid Person person
```

Comment: ok, can we do complex validation with this approach, like email regex matching, password length matching etc?

Comment: @techgeek yes, definitely

Comment: @techgeek also you should return Bad Request if email is missing